# Displaying live data from one column of Database in RecyclerView Header

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I want to create a Header for my recyclerView that displays the total amount spent.

Now my idea was that in the Adapterclass of the header I want to use a function from my Dao that gives me all the data from the table and iterate over the needed column and build the sum.

I am getting unresolved reference for the getExpenses() function and the error that my for loop needs an iterator method. Anyone knows why and can help me out?

The Dao:

```
 @Dao
 interface ReceiptDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM receipt_table ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getAllReceipts(): Flow<List<Receipts>>


    @Query("SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(total,0)), 0) From receipt_table")
    fun getSum(): Flow<List<Double>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(receipts: Receipts)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(receipts: Receipts)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(receipts: Receipts)
}
```

The Adapter

```
class HeaderAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderAdapter.HeaderViewHolder>() {
private lateinit var totalSumTextView: TextView

class HeaderViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    private val headerTotal: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerTotal)

    fun bind(totalSum: Int) {
        headerTotal.text = totalSum.toString()
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HeaderViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.history_header, parent, false)
    return HeaderViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HeaderViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(position)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 1
}

fun onDatabaseUpdate() {
    val receipts: Flow<List<Receipts>> = ReceiptDatabase.getExpenses()
    // Set the total sum
    var sum = 0.0
    for (e in receipts) {
        sum += e.total
    }
    totalSumTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum))
}
}
```

The Database :

```
 @Database(entities = [Receipts::class],version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ReceiptDatabase :RoomDatabase(){

abstract fun receiptDao(): ReceiptDao
abstract val receiptDatabase : ReceiptDatabase

//Fills Database with dummy data
    class Callback @Inject constructor( //tells Dagger how to create an intance of the class and its dependecies
        private val database: Provider<ReceiptDatabase>, //Task database is only instantiated when we call onCreate which only is called AFTER Database is craeted.
        @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)

            val dao = database.get().receiptDao()
            applicationScope.launch {
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"15.06.2021","Aldi"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"13.06.2021","Lidl"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"11.06.2021","Aldi"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"11.06.2021","Aldi"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"11.06.2021","Rewe"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"10.06.2021","Aldi"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(6.76,"07.06.2021","Ikea"))
                dao.insert(Receipts(8.96,"01.06.2021","Edeka"))
            }
        }
    }
fun getExpenses(): Flow<List<Receipts?>?> {
    return receiptDatabase.receiptDao().getAllReceipts()
}
}
```

Comment: why you're using recyclerview for just one element
also it's bad pratice to call database singleton object like that 
create callback and implement it in your activity or fragment after that 
passe it as object to the adapter

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean.